# Accesing BRMS application reboots the Server

Tags: troubleshooting, jboss

There is some issue with my BRMS server we are trying to access it from the 
command line its working fine.

But when opening the browser to use the BRMS application the server reboots

We tried every possibility for checking the issue but still no clue why its happening.

JBOSS BRMS `Standalone 6.1` 
RED HAT `6.4 64 bit`

Comment: Does it log any errors before it reboots?

Comment: We have checked every log on the server but no help. which logs do you need, So that I can pull it for you.

Comment: I would need a lot more info to know which logs are relevant.  What BRMS software (and what version) are you using?  What Linux distro? What web server? That will get us a good start.

Comment: Question updated, There is no webserver as its a standalone `ENV`.